# Jenkins cannot connect to nodes

Tags: jenkins, ssh, continuous-integration, continuous-deployment

I had a jenkins node connected and working in my jenkins server, however two days ago all agents running in the server lost the connection and they began to show this error:

`java.io.IOException: Could not copy remoting.jar into '/home/desarrollo' on agent  at hudson.plugins.sshslaves.SSHLauncher.copyAgentJar(SSHLauncher.java:717)  at hudson.plugins.sshslaves.SSHLauncher.access$300(SSHLauncher.java:113)    at hudson.plugins.sshslaves.SSHLauncher$1.call(SSHLauncher.java:457)    at hudson.plugins.sshslaves.SSHLauncher$1.call(SSHLauncher.java:423)    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)   at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829) Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: invalid len argument at com.trilead.ssh2.SFTPv3Client.read(SFTPv3Client.java:1232)    at com.trilead.ssh2.jenkins.SFTPClient$SFTPInputStream.read(SFTPClient.java:172)    at com.google.common.io.ByteStreams.toByteArrayInternal(ByteStreams.java:191)   at com.google.common.io.ByteStreams.toByteArray(ByteStreams.java:238)   at hudson.plugins.sshslaves.SSHLauncher.readInputStreamIntoByteArrayAndClose(SSHLauncher.java:775)  at hudson.plugins.sshslaves.SSHLauncher.copyAgentJar(SSHLauncher.java:686)`

I tried to delete the jar file in the node but it works for short time and then the agent goes offline again, I tried disabling nodes too but the reboot doesn't work either